# Ruby sort subarray in place

Tags: ruby, list, sorting, in-place

If I have an array in Ruby, foo, how can a sort `foo[i..j]` in-place?

I tried calling `foo[i..j].sort!` but it didn't sort the original array, just returned a sorted part of it.

Comment: List? What do you mean?

Comment: Please double-check your results: `foo = [3,1,2]`, `foo.sort! #=> [1,  2,  3]`, `foo #=> [1, 2, 3]`, What do you mean by "sublist"? btw, to have code within sentences stand out (as in this comment) surround it with backticks. Best to give an actual example (rather than `[i..j]`).

Comment: You can re-assign that segment of the array to a sorted version (`foo[i..j] = foo[i..j].sort`)

Comment: By list I meant array, sorry for the confusion. When I said sublist I meant a part (defined by the start index i and end index j) of the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort *part of* an array you need to reinject the sorted parts. The in-place modifier won't help you here because `foo[i..j]` **returns a copy**. You're sorting the copy in place, which really doesn't mean anything to the original array.

So instead, replace the original slice with a sorted version of same:

```
test = %w[ z b f d c h k z ]

test[2..6] = test[2..6].sort
# => ["c", "d", "f", "h", "k"]

test
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "h", "k", "q"]
```

Comment: Okay, I was doing that. So there's no easy way to sort a sublist in place? I mean, something like foo.sort!(startIndex, endIndex)

Comment: Nope, but if you wanted you could patch `Array` with a new method of your choosing if this is someting you're going to do often in your code.